# Why is there an infinite supply of energy in slow-roll inflation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, cosmology, cosmological-inflation, cosmological-constant

The physical model of inflation includes a metastable false vacuum, or a slow-roll field on a flat potential. In either case, I just realized how this is completely insane. With the exponential growth of physical volume, there is exponential growth in the total energy. I understand that there isn't energy conservation in GR. Redshift of photon is OK for me. But this exponential supply of energy is absolutely crazy and highly unintuitive. There is either something fundamentally wrong or a very profound answer. In either way, my physics intuition needs an overhaul.